# Instalar pod para Material Design swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, material-design, cocoapods, pods

Estoy realizando una aplicación con Xcode 9.4.1 con swift 4. Me gustaría incluir los componentes de MaterialDesign, sin embargo, no me está funcionando.

Este es mi Podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target 'ProbandoMDC' do
    pod 'MaterialComponents'
    pod 'MaterialComponents/TextFields'
end
```

cuando intento agregar el import dentro de mi ViewController recibo el mensaje: *No such module 'MaterialComponents.MaterialTextFields'*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Estoy omitiendo algo que debo hacer en Xcode sobre el proyecto? Ya intenté agregar los componenetes en la sección **Linked Frameworks and Libraries**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si estas abriendo el archivo .xcworkspace, yo realize la instalacion sin problemas con cocoapods, sin necesidad de agregar a Linked Frameworks

Comment: Hola Sergio. Definitivamente si estoy abriendo el archivo .xworkspace

Comment: intenta desinstalar y volver a instalar con xcode completamente cerrado, tambien puede funcionar limpiar el proyecto

Comment: Parece que era una omisión en mi Podfile, la instrucción `use framework`. Aqui está como quedo 

`target 'ProbandoMDC' do
  dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

pod 'MaterialComponents/TextFields'
pod 'MaterialComponents/Tabs'

end`